# rspec new syntax stub method with parameters and return fix value

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I want to stub object **A** for respond to message **next** with parameter **1** and return **"B"** String.

```
describe "some situation" do
  before do
    A = double("Some Object")
    A.stub(:next).with(1).and_return("B")
  end

  it "passes" do
    expect(A.next(1)).to eq(B)    
  end
end
```

I want to write `A.stub(:next).with(1).and_return("B")` line with new rspec syntax `A.allow...` but I could not find where to add the `with` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the new syntax works:

```
allow(A).to receive(:next).with(1).and_return("B")
```